# Apache won't restart, ssl errors

Tags: apache, ssl, debian-7.6.0

my websites are alll down, including those upon which my livelihood depends.
tail /var/log/apache/error.log gives me this:

---

[Tue Mar 01 06:07:59 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `www.tonybaldwin.info' does NOT match server name!?
[Tue Mar 01 06:07:59 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN)`mail.myownsite.me' does NOT match server name!?
[Tue Mar 01 06:07:59 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `mail.myownsite.me' does NOT match server name!?
[Tue Mar 01 06:07:59 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN)`mail.myownsite.me' does NOT match server name!?
[Tue Mar 01 06:07:59 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `mail.myownsite.me' does NOT match server name!?
[Tue Mar 01 06:07:59 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN)`mail.myownsite.me' does NOT match server name!?
[Tue Mar 01 06:07:59 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `mail.myownsite.me' does NOT match server name!?
[Tue Mar 01 06:07:59 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN)`red.liberame.org' does NOT match server name!?
[Tue Mar 01 06:07:59 2016] [error] Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Tue Mar 01 06:07:59 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch

---

is there any way to force Apache to restart despite these ssl errors, or must I recreate all of these certificates?
or how else can I resolve this problem?
one thing that really stumps me is that mail.myownsite.me is not in any apache configs or vhosts, afaik, it should only be of concern to dovecot and/or postfix, so I don't understand why it appears in the apache error.log
This is on a vps running debian jessie.

Comment: What changes were done before these errors started showing up?

Comment: I had only renewed a cert from startssl.com

Comment: perhaps I should also mention that there is also no vhost anywhere for red.liberame.org, nor has there been for over a year...so it's giving me a hard time over non-existent sites or sites that apache does not or no longer serves on this particular machine. also, the server is running Debian 8/Jessie.

Comment: none of the domains mentioned in the apache error.log with the exception of tonybaldwin.info, even have vhosts currently, so that's really got me stumped for what I'm supposed to do about the errors, especially.

Comment: the hostname on the server is myownsite.me

Comment: I a2dissmoded the sslmod, commented out the parts of every vhost mentioning port 443 and any certificates, and moved the recently updated certificate out of /etc/ssl in to my $HOME, and still can't restart apache... I'm stumped...I've got to get this server back up. please help...

Comment: I did finally get apache restarted, but I had to completely disable all SSL on all my domains (as mentioned by a2dismod ssl,plus commenting out all parts of vhosts referencing SSLEngine or certificates or port 443, etc.. , which isn't too cool...

Answer (score 1):

The above error clearly states the virtual hosts created and the certificates binded to them are not matching. Its important to understand that the certificate is binded exactly to the Url which the users type in the address bar to access the web page.

So if your domain say is www.abc.com and the binded certificate common name is 172.168.1.1 or www.xyz.com, the Apache will not start after you initiate the restart. Hence, make sure the certificate common name matches to the server name mentioned in the virtual host for the website to work properly with SSL.

Comment: thanks! the real problem is I can afford exactly 1 VPS, and it has sufficient stotage/respources to host several sites, so that's what I do and even with apache sni  there ends up resulting confusion...